# How to I get a scene to follow my sprite?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I've been trying to get my scene to follow my Player sprite but for some reason its not following. Can anyone explain why? I've tried following tutorials but no luck. This is my current code:

```
[self setViewpointCenter:Player.position];


    -(void)setViewpointCenter:(CGPoint) position {
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    int x = MAX(position.x, winSize.width / 2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, winSize.height / 2);
    x = MIN(x, (theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width) - winSize.width / 2);
    y = MIN(y, (theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height) - winSize.height / 2);
    CGPoint actualPosition = ccp(x, y);

    CGPoint centerOfView = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    CGPoint viewPoint = ccpSub(centerOfView, actualPosition);
    self.position = viewPoint;
}
```

Comment: are you aware of CCFollow action which allows a layer to follow one of its child nodes?

Comment: Ohh thanks didn't know ccfollow can also effect layers.

Comment: actually it only works if run on a layer

Comment: tried using [layer runAction: [CCFollow actionWithTarget:Player]]; & CCLayer *layer; but no luck. Any ideas? It makes sense.

Comment: try it in a new, empty project. It works. Just don't change position or run other move actions on the layer. And make sure layer is kind of class CCLayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapped my original code and replaced it with a clean code recommended by LearnCocos2D

```
[self runAction: [CCFollow actionWithTarget:Player]];
```

Thanks LearnCocos2D, once again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do clearly,
but I think maybe you want the map to move behind the player?
If this is the case you could try moving the map instead of self. 
I have a very similar function in my project, with basically one line different,
and that is the last line.

```
self.position = viewPoint;
```

This is how it appears in my code:

```
map.position = viewPoint;
```

Hope that helps!